# Connect one web app server to wo sharepoint farms

Tags: farm, web-app-server

I wonder if it's possible to connect the web app server to developer and testing farm.
is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are in the same domain(?) and run under the same protocol (i guess http for test?), this should not be a problem.

Microsoft writes the following:

> An Office Web Apps Server farm can provide Office services to multiple on-premises hosts, and you can scale out the farm from one server to multiple servers as your organization’s needs grow.

Office web apps run as a single product compared to OWA for SharePoint 2010.

Just create the connections from the different farms to the wac server using the New-SPWOPIBinding cmdlt.

[New-SPWOPIBinding](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219441.aspx)

[Configure Office Web Apps for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx)

[Office Web Apps Server overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219437.aspx)